# Is there a way for an Icinga2 host to be both master and satellite?

Tags: monitoring, icinga2

Is there a way for an Icinga2 host to be both master and satellite? I want to set it up in a way that two masters monitor each other in case one shuts down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for not answering Yes nor No. I would rather answer the second part of the question.

If you want to monitor two Icinga masters from each other, you can use more than one approach.

If you want to have two independent monitoring clusters - you can deploy two different Icinga2 clusters, with each cluster monitoring the other one.

One can also deploy Icinga2 in [Highly Available](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/06-distributed-monitoring/#high-availability-master-with-clients) setup. Then you can deploy one Icinga2 master instance where you put your config. After its setup, you should deploy second master, which will synchronize configuration from the first master. These two masters (more exactly [Endpoints](https://www.icinga.com/docs/icinga2/latest/doc/06-distributed-monitoring/#endpoints)) should be put in same zone, they can both run `checker` feature to run the checks. To run notifications, you should also enable `notification`

All other hosts (satellites) should be connected to both masters.

To ensure monitoring of one master from the second one, you should use `command_endpoint` setting to schedule to check on the right host.

So the answer is: **You can deploy two Icinga2 masters, which will share their monitoring load. They can also monitor each other.**